# add thumbnail into InlineQueryResultAudio audio in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, inline

I having a problem with uploading an audio using InlineQueryResultAudio from google drive but I don't get the thumbnail inside the audio.
Ps:I add the image inside the mp3 before uploading

```
from uuid import uuid4
from telegram import InlineQueryResultArticle, InputTextMessageContent, Update,InlineQueryResultAudio,InputTextMessageContent


def build_inline_query_result_article_songs(result, url_song, artistt):
  iid = str(uuid4())
  r = InlineQueryResultAudio(
    id=iid,
    title=result.title(),
    audio_url=url_song,
    performer=artistt.title()
  )
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I use InlineQueryResultCachedAudio instead of InlineQueryResultAudio,so the thumbnail upload with the song